# ASP.NET jQuery not working from subdirectory

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

I write ASP.NET application and I want to use jQuery DataTables.

In Master Page (which is not in root) I include scripts in code behind:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    ScriptManagerSM.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference(Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery.min.js")));
    ScriptManagerSM.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference(Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-ui.min.js")));
    ScriptManagerSM.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference(Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js")));
    ScriptManagerSM.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference(Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/setup.js")));
    Page.Header.DataBind();
}
```

In page I have just pure html:
    `<table class="table display">

        <thead>

            <tr>

                <th>Header</th>

                <th>Header 2</th>

            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <tr class="gradeX">

                <td>Cell 1</td>

                <td>Cell 2</td> 
            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>`

jQuery is called by class selector in my setup.js:
`$(function() { 
var oTable = $('.table').dataTable( {

        "bJQueryUI": true,

        "sScrollX": "",

        "bSortClasses": false,

        "aaSorting": [[0,'asc']],

        "bAutoWidth": true,

        "bInfo": true,

        "sScrollY": "100%",

        "sScrollX": "100%",

        "bScrollCollapse": true,

        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

        "bRetrieve": true

    } );

});`

Everything is working on pages placed in root. But on pages in subfolders jQuery is not fired. It looks like some path trouble, but I can't see.

Thanks for help o..o

*edit: setup script added*
*edit 2: added calling of jQuery*
*edit 3: added $(function() { to js code above (already existing in my real code, just missing here*

Comment: You should use Firebug for Firefox and see if you have any JS errors.  You can also look at the load order of all the content, to make sure jQuery is loaded before your other scripts.  Finally, make sure you are checking if the DOM is ready via $(document).ready({});.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document needs to load before you run this so change this:

```
var oTable = $('.table').dataTable( {
"bJQueryUI": true,
"sScrollX": "",
"bSortClasses": false,
"aaSorting": [[0,'asc']],
"bAutoWidth": true,
"bInfo": true,
"sScrollY": "100%",
"sScrollX": "100%",
"bScrollCollapse": true,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"bRetrieve": true
} );
```

To this:

```
$(function(){

var oTable = $('.table').dataTable( {
"bJQueryUI": true,
"sScrollX": "",
"bSortClasses": false,
"aaSorting": [[0,'asc']],
"bAutoWidth": true,
"bInfo": true,
"sScrollY": "100%",
"sScrollX": "100%",
"bScrollCollapse": true,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"bRetrieve": true
} );

});
```

Comment: It's rendering:
`../js/jquery.min.js`
`../js/jquery-ui.min.js`
`../js/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js`

which is right, bu still not working. Path seems right, jQuery just not fired, weird..

Comment: Where on your page are you running your setup scripts? Are you sure that your script files are loaded before you are trying to use them?

Comment: My setup scripts are loaded right after those stated in my post above (I updated the code in my first post):

`ScriptManagerSM.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference(Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/setup.js")));
Page.Header.DataBind();`

But it is loaded on master page. Nothing I'm loading on particular pages. So - I'm not sure, if they are loaded before pages are trying to use them. But problem is only on subdir pages, so I suppose they are loaded in correct time..

Comment: Try updating your question with the code where you using the scripts in the html.

Comment: Thanks for a help. I have already js code between `$(function(){` and `});` in setup.js, but with another settings, so it's why I miss it here in code above. I edit it.